# Explicit convergence of Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff

Tags: lie-algebras, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let g be a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra over C. The Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff series defines a (multivariable) analytic function from a neighborhood of 0 in g \times g \to g. What is the domain of (absolute) convergence of this function?

Answer (score 6):

You might try [On the convergence and optimization of the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2003.09.010), via google.